# Find max value for each partition in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
Make    RfR ID  Test ID
VOLVO   8971    1
VOLVO   8173    28
VOLVO   8554    1
VOLVO   8556    1
VOLVO   8409    1
VOLVO   8712    1
VOLVO   8408    1
VOLVO   2056    35    
KIA     8545    8
KIA     8157    1
KIA     7847    1
KIA     713     2
KIA     8551    3
KIA     8453    2
KIA     8466    8
```

Here I am trying to output a table with rows that correspond to a maximum value for Test ID for each make (hence partitioned by make).

The output should look something like this:

```
Make    RfR ID  Test ID
VOLVO   2056    35
KIA     8545    28
```

In SQL I would use 'partition by' but yet to find of doing something similar with pandas

Comment: Is the 28 in your expected output a typo for 8?

Comment: @EduardKim, could you please post corresponding SQL with `over(partition by ...)`, so i could understand the question correctly?

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, you want "rows that correspond to a maximum value for Test ID for each make".  To do this, I'd find out indices of maximum values by make, and then use those to index into `df`:

```
>>> df.groupby("Make")["Test ID"].idxmax()
Make
KIA      8
VOLVO    7
Name: Test ID, dtype: int64
>>> df.loc[df.groupby("Make")["Test ID"].idxmax()]
    Make  RfR ID  Test ID
8    KIA    8545        8
7  VOLVO    2056       35
```

If your index isn't unique you could `.reset_index()` first.

Note that this will retrieve the first maximum in case of duplicates (so KIA 8545 instead of KIA 8466, which both have Test ID==8.)  If you instead want them all, you could get that too, using `transform`:

```
>>> df.loc[df["Test ID"] == df.groupby("Make")["Test ID"].transform("max")]
     Make  RfR ID  Test ID
7   VOLVO    2056       35
8     KIA    8545        8
14    KIA    8466        8
```

Comment: I think your answer covers more cases, so i would recommend OP to use your solution, +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print(df.groupby('Make').max())
```

Test:

```
import six
import pandas as pd


data = """\
Make    RfRID  TestID
VOLVO   8971    1
VOLVO   8173    28
VOLVO   8554    1
VOLVO   8556    1
VOLVO   8409    1
VOLVO   8712    1
VOLVO   8408    1
VOLVO   2056    35    
KIA     8545    8
KIA     8157    1
KIA     7847    1
KIA     713     2
KIA     8551    3
KIA     8453    2
KIA     8466    8
"""

df = pd.read_csv(six.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
print(df)

print(df.groupby('Make').max())
```

Output:

```
       RfRID  TestID
Make
KIA     8551       8
VOLVO   8971      35
```

PS optionally you may want to reset the index:

```
df.groupby('Make').max().reset_index()
```

Comment: This isn't quite what the OP is after: you're finding the maximum of the columns after grouping by Make, the OP wants rows corresponding to the maximum Test ID by Make.